# HTML input into Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a website which can tell the circumference of a circle when the user inputs the radius. I've done the code, but its not working. Can you tell me why?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
 <body>
 <form id="ty">
 Give radius: <input type="number" input id="radius">
 </form>
 <p id="sum"> htht </p>
<button type="button" onclick="my()"> Click on me</button>
<script>
Function my() {
var r= document.getElementById("radius");
var a= r*2;
 document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML=a;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting an error "NaN" when I click on the button

Comment: No, you don't. You get `error ReferenceError: my is not defined`.

Comment: <input type="number" input id="radius"> syntax error - delete one input.

Comment: no, I am getting "NaN"

Comment: Kai Mattern, not working

Comment: First change Function to function, then may be you get NaN

Comment: Move the `<script>` in the `<head>`. Here you don't need the body to be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Working HTML demo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Radius to Circumference</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="ty">
<ol>
<li>Give radius: <input type="number" name="radius"></input></li>
<li><input type="button" onClick="my();" value="convert"></input></li>
<li>Get circumference: <input type="number" name="sum"></input></li>
</ol>
</form>
<script LANGUAGE="Javascript">
function my() {
var r = document.ty.radius.value*1;
var a = r*2;
document.ty.sum.value = a;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

- when writing HTML, you should be certain to use proper semantics.
  Specify a doctype, character set and language!
- avoid using buttons that say things like "Click on me!" This is
  redundant because the user has to read what they're going to do
  before they do it. Instead, write what the button will do
  on the button itself (in this case, "Convert" is what I used).
- you did not include a title in your head.
- and  are two different elements with different
  purposes. In this case, you want .
- "function" should not be capitalized.
- your r variable did not contain the number the user put in, but
  rather, contained all the properties of the input element. You never 
  specified you wanted the number it contained, so instead, the
  variable r contained all the information it could obtain about the
  "radius" element including it's colour, it's size, and other useless 
  things you don't need. You are looking for it's value, hence why I
  added .value on the end of that line.
- I also added *1 to the end of r's line, so that if the user by
  any chance did not enter a valid number, Javascript will correct that
  issue (multiplying by one gives the same result but parsed into a number).
- you were using the p element for the sum, but that wouldn't be a
  paragraph now, would it?
- I used an ordered list to add 1, 2, and 3 to the beginning of each
  step.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean:

```
var r = document.getElementById("radius").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

getElementByID returns the element, not its value. element*2 = NaN.

You want.

```
var r = document.getElementById("radius").value;
```

Also, you might want to parse the integer just in case:

```
var r = parseInt(document.getElementById("radius").value);
```

Comment: An <input> doesnt have innerhtml, it has a value.

Comment: @Al.G. I was only looking at the P. My bad.

Comment: @Darth_Coder Good news! Please highlight your preferred answer. Whichever it was ;)

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, from [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_text_value) you can find you need to change:

```
var r= document.getElementById("radius");
```

to

```
var r= document.getElementById("radius").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have written whith uppercase F the function, note that the
   javascript is case sensitive.
2. the value of the input element can get using the .value property.
3. in the input form element does not need twice using the input
   keyword, only once on begin.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a nicer way to write that, with some minor improvements.**

1. it's preferred to write the javascript in the head.
2. by defining the various elements onload later you have faster&easier access to them.
3. also inline javascript is not suggested, don't write js inside html attributes.

Then talking about your errors:

`function` is not `Function`

`document.getElementById('radius')` should be `document.getElementById('radius').value`

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var radiusBox,sumBox,button;

function my(){
 sumBox.innerHTML=radiusBox.value*2 
 // the use of textContent is more appropiate but works only on newer browsers
}

window.onload=function(){
 radiusBox=document.getElementById('radius');
 sumBox=document.getElementById('sum');
 button=document.getElementById('button');
 button.onclick=my
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <form id="ty">
  Give radius:<input type="number" id="radius">
 </form>
 <p id="sum">Enter a number</p>
 <button id="button">Click on me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

writing it this way it is compatible with every browser that supports javascript, a newer proper way would be using `addEventListener` to add the `load` and the `click` handler thus also allowing you to add multiple event handlers, but old ie's wouldn'ty work.also textContent could have prblems...

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/frma0zup/

if you have any questions just ask.